# Why were the UN Sustainable Goals created?

Tags: international-relations, united-nations, sustainable-development

So far, very few to none of the [Sustainable Goals](https://www.un.org/sustainabledevelopment/) have been achieved. What led to the creation of the SDGs, and were they actually expected to be achieved?

Comment: One cannot always expect to achieve all goals and sometimes it may even be good to have very ambitious goals that likely will not be achieved. If the goals are very important, missing them might be an important reminder to up the effort in the future. This are just general arguments, I don't know anything about the specific case. Not achieving these goals surely doesn't look very good. Sustainability has many advantages in the long run.

Comment: @Trilarion True, but having a lot of dilute, wishful-thinking ("No Poverty", "Gender Equality"...), even if very worthy, goals can very much get in the way of aiming for a few achievable goals with actual done/not done metrics.  So, say  -10% of people living under $2/day in 5 years, instead of No Poverty.   On the positive side, no risk of identifiable shortcomings by the UN department heads with this lot.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Less ambitious goals might be easier to reach but would be less important to reach. We should remember that the risks aren't symmetrical here. Doing too little hurts much more than doing too much with regard to the environment. The size of the goals probably is reflecting the severity of the situation. Maybe the UN just wants to make sure it's never accused of understating the problem. Like: come on guys we always told you exactly what needs to be done, never hide the true goals, but you didn't listen, so it's not our fault ... or something like this.

Comment: The UN has few ways to reward achievement or punish failure. So establishing goals that are relatively easy to attain gains little. Instead they set lofty goals that everyone should strive for. If they only achieve 10-25%, this will still be significant.